# Avoid join when Auth users laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

- User: [id,username,password]
- Producer: [id,user_id,...]
- Admin: [id,user_id,...]

I've configured Authentication through User table. 
So, if I get logged in when I execute `Auth::user()` I only can access to the user's fields. However, I would need be able to get producer's fields. I have to say that, a user can be Producer or Admin but not both.

Do you know good documentation or something to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not clear what your models are.  Users can be either producers or admins?

Comment: Your requirement look like to call ACL method. try to acl with your application.

Answer (score 1):

You class should hasMany relation to it

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    public function producers()
    { 
        return $this->hasMany('Producer');
    } 
}

$user = Auth::user();

print_r($user->producers);
```

Comment: The problem is that not all users are Producer, some of them can be Admin, so this seems not a good solution, don't you think so?

Comment: You can add scopes to your query, assuming you want to do that you scan add scopeAdmin() and add your query.